# Get list of .cpp files from xcode project

Tags: xcode, parsing, project

I am converting from xcode3 project to premake, I need to get list of .cpp files from my xcode3 project. Is there any way to do it? Some script or xcode project file parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, do this steps:

> 1) Open your project in XCode3
>
> 2) Click Cmd + Shift + C

Now you will see a Class Browser where all classes of project. Do you mean this?